# Square Connect - Customizing the Form

Tags: php, forms, square-connect

I am trying to create a payment form that allows a child care center to accept payments that the customer specifies by typing in a number. I have gotten the basic form to work with the basic setup found on their [Github](https://github.com/square/connect-api-examples/tree/master/connect-examples/v2/php_payment), so I am setup and running correctly. My problem is that I am a front end designer and cannot figure out how to get other fields to push through with the card info. I have all of the required files to run the Square Connect API. Here is the relevant code I have so far...

My Form (in payment.php):

```
  <script>
    var sqPaymentForm = new SqPaymentForm({
      // Replace this value with your application's ID (available from the merchant dashboard).
      // If you're just testing things out, replace this with your _Sandbox_ application ID,
      // which is also available there.
      applicationId: 'MY-APPLICATION-ID',
      inputClass: 'sq-input',
      cardNumber: {
        elementId: 'sq-card-number',
        placeholder: "0000 0000 0000 0000"
      },
      cvv: {
        elementId: 'sq-cvv',
        placeholder: 'CVV'
      },
      expirationDate: {
        elementId: 'sq-expiration-date',
        placeholder: 'MM/YY'
      },
      postalCode: {
        elementId: 'sq-postal-code',
        placeholder: 'Postal Code'
      },
      // inputStyles: [
      //   // Because this object provides no value for mediaMaxWidth or mediaMinWidth,
      //   // these styles apply for screens of all sizes, unless overridden by another
      //   // input style below.
      //   {
      //     fontSize: '14px',
      //     padding: '3px'
      //   },
      //   // These styles are applied to inputs ONLY when the screen width is 400px
      //   // or smaller. Note that because it doesn't specify a value for padding,
      //   // the padding value in the previous object is preserved.
      //   {
      //     mediaMaxWidth: '400px',
      //     fontSize: '18px',
      //   }
      // ],
      callbacks: {
        cardNonceResponseReceived: function(errors, nonce, cardData) {
          if (errors) {
            var errorDiv = document.getElementById('errors');
            errorDiv.innerHTML = "";
            errors.forEach(function(error) {
              var p = document.createElement('p');
              p.innerHTML = error.message;
              errorDiv.appendChild(p);
            });
          } else {
            // This alert is for debugging purposes only.
            alert('Nonce received! ' + nonce + ' ' + JSON.stringify(cardData));
            // Assign the value of the nonce to a hidden form element
            var nonceField = document.getElementById('card-nonce');
            nonceField.value = nonce;
            // Submit the form
            document.getElementById('form').submit();
          }
        },
        unsupportedBrowserDetected: function() {
          // Alert the buyer that their browser is not supported
        }
      }
    });
    function submitButtonClick(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      sqPaymentForm.requestCardNonce();
    }
</script>
<form class="uk-form billing-form uk-flex uk-flex-wrap" id="form" novalidate action="/payment-portal/process-card.php" method="post">
    <div class="personal-info uk-flex uk-flex-column">
            <div class="billing-form-group uk-flex uk-flex-space-between">
            <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" id="given_name" class="uk-form-large" style="margin-bottom: 1rem;">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" id="family_name" class="uk-form-large">
        </div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Billing Address" class="uk-form-large">
        <input type="text" placeholder="City" class="uk-form-large">
        <select class="uk-form-large">
            <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
            <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
            <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
            <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
            <option value="CA">California</option>
            <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
            <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
            <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
            <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
            <option value="FL">Florida</option>
            <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
            <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
            <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
            <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
            <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
            <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
            <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
            <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
            <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
            <option value="ME">Maine</option>
            <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
            <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
            <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
            <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
            <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
            <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
            <option value="MT">Montana</option>
            <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
            <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
            <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
            <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
            <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
            <option value="NY">New York</option>
            <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
            <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
            <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
            <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
            <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
            <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
            <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
            <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
            <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
            <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
            <option value="TX">Texas</option>
            <option value="UT">Utah</option>
            <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
            <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
            <option value="WA">Washington</option>
            <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
            <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
            <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Zip Code" id="sq-postal-code" class="uk-form-large">
    </div>
    <div class="card-info uk-flex uk-flex-column">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Phone Number" class="uk-form-large">
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" class="uk-form-large">
        <div class="billing-form-group uk-flex uk-flex-space-between">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Amount" class="uk-form-large">
            <select class="uk-form-large">
                <option>Visa</option>
                <option>Mastercard</option>
                <option>Discover</option>
                <option>American Express</option>
            </select> 
        </div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Card Number" id="sq-card-number" class="uk-form-large">
        <div class="exp-cvv-group uk-flex uk-flex-space-between">
            <input type="text" placeholder="MM/YY" id="sq-expiration-date" class="uk-form-large">
            <input type="text" placeholder="CVV" id="sq-cvv" class="uk-form-large uk-form-width-mini">
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="card-nonce" name="nonce">
    <div class="billing-button-container">
        <input type="submit" onclick="submitButtonClick(event)" id="card-nonce-submit" class="button mid-blue-button billing-button"></div>
    </div>
</form>
<div id="errors"></div>
```

My Processor (in process-card.php):

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
# Replace these values. You probably want to start with your Sandbox credentials
# to start: https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/using-sandbox/
# The ID of the business location to associate processed payments with.
# If you're testing things out, use a sandbox location ID.
#
# See [Retrieve your business's locations](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/getting-started/#retrievemerchantprofile)
# for an easy way to get your business's location IDs. If the php page is not rendering, make sure 
# that error reporting is turned on. If you get an error that says, "Fatal error: Uncaught 
# exception 'SquareConnect\ApiException' with message 'API call to 
# https://connect.squareup.com/v2/locations failed, but for an unknown reason." This is most likely 
# caused by blocked outgoing ports in the web server. Contact host provider for resolution.
$location_id = 'MY-LOCATION-ID';
# The access token to use in all Connect API requests. Use your *sandbox* access
# token if you're just testing things out.
$access_token = 'MY-ACCESS-TOKEN';
# Helps ensure this code has been reached via form submission
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') {
  error_log("Received a non-POST request");
  echo "Request not allowed";
  http_response_code(405);
  return;
}
# Fail if the card form didn't send a value for `nonce` to the server
$nonce = $_POST['nonce'];
if (is_null($nonce)) {
  echo "Invalid card data";
  http_response_code(422);
  return;
}
$transaction_api = new \SquareConnect\Api\TransactionApi();
$request_body = array (
  "card_nonce" => $nonce,
  # Monetary amounts are specified in the smallest unit of the applicable currency.
  # This amount is in cents. It's also hard-coded for $1.00, which isn't very useful.
  "amount_money" => array (
    "amount" => 100,
    "currency" => "USD"
  ),
  # Every payment you process with the SDK must have a unique idempotency key.
  # If you're unsure whether a particular payment succeeded, you can reattempt
  # it with the same idempotency key without worrying about double charging
  # the buyer.
  "idempotency_key" => uniqid()
);
# The SDK throws an exception if a Connect endpoint responds with anything besides
# a 200-level HTTP code. This block catches any exceptions that occur from the request.
try {
  $result = $transaction_api->charge($access_token, $location_id, $request_body);
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($result);
  echo "</pre>";
} catch (\SquareConnect\ApiException $e) {
  echo "Caught exception!<br/>";
  print_r("<strong>Response body:</strong><br/>");
  echo "<pre>"; var_dump($e->getResponseBody()); echo "</pre>";
  echo "<br/><strong>Response headers:</strong><br/>";
  echo "<pre>"; var_dump($e->getResponseHeaders()); echo "</pre>";
}
```

Please note that I have replaced all references to MY-anything to the correct values for my application. (As I said, I have the basic form working.)

I am not looking for anyone to write all of the code per se, but can someone point me in the direction of how to get started. I need to get the customer information to push through with the payment with maybe a note to list the child(ren). I know that I will have to add the form field to incorporate the note, but I don't even know how to make the name work, so I need to get that down first, then I can figure out the rest. My other thing is I need to know how to add the amount field that the parent can put in how much they want to pay. I can see the part in process-card.php here:

```
"amount_money" => array (
  "amount" => 100,
  "currency" => "USD"
),
```

I am not sure if that is just saying what the minimum amount to charge is, but it looks like it is only charging $1.00 every time no matter what. I know it is not connected to the form field, but I am not sure how to connect it.

I have read the documentation [here](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/processing-payment-php/) and [here](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2/#connectapiv2conventions), but most of this is Greek to me. If someone could help me get the custom amount working, I think I could figure out the rest. Let me know if I need to provide any additional information.

Comment: Has anyone found a way to do EVERYTHING on the client side? I guess that would potentially be insecure as it would show the Access Token.. darn. But still, is there a AJAX way of submitting the nonce with the money object? Im assuming all the PHP, Java and Node APIs just use their REST api.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple things

- In your `process-card.php` it might be easier to get your locations from the API each time instead of hard coding them in (if you only plan on having one location)

  ```
  $location_api = new \SquareConnect\Api\LocationApi();
  $location_id = $location_api->listLocations($access_token)->getLocations()[0]->getId();
  ```
- At a high level, the credit card nonce is passed in a form along with all the other named variables in the form. I've edited your code to pass through more information and display it on the other side.

`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.squareup.com/v2/paymentform"></script>
<script>
    var sqPaymentForm = new SqPaymentForm({
      // Replace this value with your application's ID (available from the merchant dashboard).
      // If you're just testing things out, replace this with your _Sandbox_ application ID,
      // which is also available there.
      applicationId: 'XXXXX',
      inputClass: 'sq-input',
      cardNumber: {
        elementId: 'sq-card-number',
        placeholder: "0000 0000 0000 0000"
      },
      cvv: {
        elementId: 'sq-cvv',
        placeholder: 'CVV'
      },
      expirationDate: {
        elementId: 'sq-expiration-date',
        placeholder: 'MM/YY'
      },
      postalCode: {
        elementId: 'sq-postal-code',
        placeholder: 'Postal Code'
      },
      // inputStyles: [
      //   // Because this object provides no value for mediaMaxWidth or mediaMinWidth,
      //   // these styles apply for screens of all sizes, unless overridden by another
      //   // input style below.
      //   {
      //     fontSize: '14px',
      //     padding: '3px'
      //   },
      //   // These styles are applied to inputs ONLY when the screen width is 400px
      //   // or smaller. Note that because it doesn't specify a value for padding,
      //   // the padding value in the previous object is preserved.
      //   {
      //     mediaMaxWidth: '400px',
      //     fontSize: '18px',
      //   }
      // ],
      callbacks: {
        cardNonceResponseReceived: function(errors, nonce, cardData) {
            if (errors) {
                var errorDiv = document.getElementById('errors');
                errorDiv.innerHTML = "";
                errors.forEach(function(error) {
                    var p = document.createElement('p');
                    p.innerHTML = error.message;
                    errorDiv.appendChild(p);
                });
            } else {
            // This alert is for debugging purposes only.
            alert('Nonce received! ' + nonce + ' ' + JSON.stringify(cardData));
            // Assign the value of the nonce to a hidden form element
            var nonceField = document.getElementById('card-nonce');
            nonceField.value = nonce;
            // Submit the form
            document.getElementById('form').submit();
        }
    },
    unsupportedBrowserDetected: function() {
          // Alert the buyer that their browser is not supported
      }
  }
});
    function submitButtonClick(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        sqPaymentForm.requestCardNonce();
    }
</script>
<form class="uk-form billing-form uk-flex uk-flex-wrap" id="form" novalidate action="/payment-portal/process-card.php" method="post">
    <div class="personal-info uk-flex uk-flex-column">
        <div class="billing-form-group uk-flex uk-flex-space-between">
            <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" id="given_name" class="uk-form-large" style="margin-bottom: 1rem;">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" id="family_name" class="uk-form-large">
        </div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Billing Address" class="uk-form-large">
        <input type="text" placeholder="City" class="uk-form-large">
        <select class="uk-form-large">
            <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
            <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
            <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
            <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
            <option value="CA">California</option>
            <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
            <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
            <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
            <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
            <option value="FL">Florida</option>
            <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
            <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
            <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
            <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
            <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
            <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
            <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
            <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
            <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
            <option value="ME">Maine</option>
            <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
            <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
            <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
            <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
            <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
            <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
            <option value="MT">Montana</option>
            <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
            <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
            <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
            <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
            <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
            <option value="NY">New York</option>
            <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
            <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
            <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
            <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
            <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
            <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
            <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
            <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
            <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
            <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
            <option value="TX">Texas</option>
            <option value="UT">Utah</option>
            <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
            <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
            <option value="WA">Washington</option>
            <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
            <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
            <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Zip Code" id="sq-postal-code" class="uk-form-large">
    </div>
    <div class="card-info uk-flex uk-flex-column">
    <input name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone Number" class="uk-form-large">
        <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" class="uk-form-large">
        <div class="billing-form-group uk-flex uk-flex-space-between">
            <input name="amount" type="text" placeholder="Amount" class="uk-form-large">
            <select class="uk-form-large">
                <option>Visa</option>
                <option>Mastercard</option>
                <option>Discover</option>
                <option>American Express</option>
            </select> 
        </div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Card Number" id="sq-card-number" value="4111111111111111" class="uk-form-large">
        <div class="exp-cvv-group uk-flex uk-flex-space-between">
            <input type="text" placeholder="MM/YY" value="0121" id="sq-expiration-date" class="uk-form-large">
            <input type="text" placeholder="CVV" id="sq-cvv" class="uk-form-large uk-form-width-mini">
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="card-nonce" name="nonce">
    <div class="billing-button-container">
        <input type="submit" onclick="submitButtonClick(event)" id="card-nonce-submit" class="button mid-blue-button billing-button">
    </div>
</div>
</form>
<div id="errors"></div>
```

---

```
<?php
include 'vendor/autoload.php';

$access_token = 'XXXXXX';

echo'<pre>';
var_dump($_POST);
echo '</pre>';

$location_api = new \SquareConnect\Api\LocationApi();

$location_id = $location_api->listLocations($access_token)->getLocations()[0]->getId();
# Helps ensure this code has been reached via form submission
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') {
  error_log("Received a non-POST request");
  echo "Request not allowed";
  http_response_code(405);
  return;
}
# Fail if the card form didn't send a value for `nonce` to the server
$nonce = $_POST['nonce'];
if (is_null($nonce)) {
  echo "Invalid card data";
  http_response_code(422);
  return;
}

$transaction_api = new \SquareConnect\Api\TransactionApi();
$request_body = array (
  "card_nonce" => $nonce,
  # Monetary amounts are specified in the smallest unit of the applicable currency.
  # This amount is in cents. It's also hard-coded for $1.00, which isn't very useful.
  "amount_money" => array (
    "amount" => $_POST['amount']*100,
    "currency" => "USD"
  ),
  # Every payment you process with the SDK must have a unique idempotency key.
  # If you're unsure whether a particular payment succeeded, you can reattempt
  # it with the same idempotency key without worrying about double charging
  # the buyer.
  "idempotency_key" => uniqid()
);
# The SDK throws an exception if a Connect endpoint responds with anything besides
# a 200-level HTTP code. This block catches any exceptions that occur from the request.
try {
  $result = $transaction_api->charge($access_token, $location_id, $request_body);
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($result);
  echo "</pre>";
} catch (\SquareConnect\ApiException $e) {
  echo "Caught exception!<br/>";
  print_r("<strong>Response body:</strong><br/>");
  echo "<pre>"; var_dump($e->getResponseBody()); echo "</pre>";
  echo "<br/><strong>Response headers:</strong><br/>";
  echo "<pre>"; var_dump($e->getResponseHeaders()); echo "</pre>";
}
```

Comment: OK. I have implemented that code, now my response page shows this at the top:

Comment: array(6) {
  ["given_name"]=>
  string(4) "Jane"
  ["family_name"]=>
  string(3) "Doe"
  ["phone"]=>
  string(10) "5559995485"
  ["email"]=>
  string(11) "you@you.com"
  ["amount"]=>
  string(5) "90.00"
  ["nonce"]=>
  string(27) "CBASEIvZRCH2c91VDWlFoNAtDeo"
}

Comment: Does that mean it will all show up now in square if I use my real credentials?

Comment: just remove the`echo'<pre>';
var_dump($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
`